# Windows 7 Home Premium update error 80070005

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I get error # 80070005 whenever I try to update Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit for the past month and a half. It tells me Windows cannot search for updates. I have tried to use System Restore, but it keeps failing..

Comment: Maybe read through [this thread from Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/windows-update-error-windowsupdate-80070005/08bce349-5c44-4e02-a15f-0113c9d28aca), and see if something works out for you. Seems like a common error, so there are a couple of answers already.

Comment: Does it happen for all the updates or some specific ones ? Have you checked **windowsupdate.log** ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasetup/thread/61ce9777-aaac-41b5-ac02-eae76759d1d3/) your account may be a member of the Administrators and Guest security groups. There's also the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) (SURT) that can help with WU problems.

[Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasetup/thread/95edbee4-a75c-48ad-91d1-5316a96f9567/) is a bunch of things to try, as well.